# Android SDK Build-tools 22.0.1 inventando pastas dentro de res no APK gerado

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk

Estou utilizando o `Android Studio 1.2.1.1`, com o `Gradle 2.2.1`, e esse é um trecho (a parte relevante) da minha minha estrutura de pastas de recursos:

```
res
 |- layout
 |- layout-v21
 |- values
 |- values-v11
 |- values-v13
 |- values-v14
 |- values-v21
 |- xml
```

Quando eu gero o APK com o `Android SDK Build-tools 20.0.0`, essa mesma estrutura é a encontrada dentro do arquivo APK (o que pode ser verificado abrindo o arquivo APK com vários programas de compactação de arquivos, como o 7-zip).

Contudo, quando eu altero para o `Android SDK Build-tools 22.0.1`, a estrutura de pastas dentro do APK fica parecida com essa abaixo:

```
res
 |- layout
 |- layout-v11
 |- layout-v21
 |- values
 |- values-v11
 |- values-v13
 |- values-v14
 |- values-v21
 |- xml
 |- xml-v14
 |- xml-v17
```

Detalhe para as pastas `layout-v11`, `xml-v14` e `xml-v17` que **não fazem parte** do meu projeto.

Isso, além de impactar no tamanho final do arquivo APK, me deixa preocupado. O que estou fazendo errado? Existe algum configuração nova na versão `22.0.1`?

Por hora, resolvi o "problema" apenas permanecendo com a versão `20.0.0`, mas gostaria de saber como resolver isso, para migrar para a versão mais nova, sem que pastas e recursos apareçam no APK.

### Atualização

Depois de muita procura pela internet (sem sucesso) e muitos testes, creio ter descoberto o que faz com que o `Android SDK Build-tools 22.0.1` "invente" as tais pastas no APK.

Fiz alguns testes iniciais com as pastas `layout` e `layout-v21`. Dentre todos os arquivos XML dentro da pasta `layout`, alguns deles possuem elementos com os seguintes atributos:

```
android:splitMotionEvents
android:nextFocusForward
```

Ambos atributos pertencem à API 11, e a API mínima suportada pelo meu projeto é API 10.

Assim, ao que tudo indica, durante a geração do APK, o `Android SDK Build-tools 22.0.1` manteve uma cópia dos meus layouts **removendo** os atributos mencionados, e criou uma pasta `layout-v11` onde manteve os layouts **com** os atributos, do jeito que eu os criei.

Esse comportamento é estranho, porque a própria IDE diz que não é errado manter atributos novos em layouts que serão utilizados com API's antigas (ela diz, e já testei inúmeras vezes: dispositivos com API's antigas simplesmente ignoram esses atributos silenciosamente).

*Não adicionei isso como resposta porque ainda preciso realizar mais testes para confirmar essa teoria.*

Comment: Eu posso estar enganado, mas isto acontece como um tipo de backup e compatibilidade, porém faz algum tempo que não trabalho com Android (tanto que eu usava Eclipse na época)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento E você sabe como desabilitar isso no Android Studio?

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas acho que isso não é "desabilitavel", não posso informar ao certo, mas até o domingo eu instalo o androidstudio e vou testar :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento chegou a alguma conclusão? :)

Comment: carlos a minha internet não está ajudando rs, estou ainda baixando :( pensei que meu colega tive-se o androidstudio, mas ele só tinha o eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Algumas características do [*Material Design*](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) como o [Material Theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) e as atividades de transições customizadas estão apenas disponíveis no Android 5.0 (API level 21) e superior. No entanto, você pode projetar seus aplicativos para fazer uso desses recursos quando executados em dispositivos que suportam a concepção de material e ainda ser compatível com dispositivos que executam versões anteriores do Android.

As pastas como `layout-v11`, `values-v11`, `xml-v14`, etc. são criadas para prover compatibilidade do [*Material Design*](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) para versões mais antigas do Android.

Note que você também pode criar pastas customizadas para tornar o "visual" ou "estrutura" do aplicativo diferente para cada dispositivo.

<sup>(Fonte: [Developer Material Compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html))</sup>

Comment: Sim! Essas essas pastas são criadas normalmente durante a criação de um novo projeto. Minha questão é que já tenho um projeto existente, e as pastas apontadas na questão aparecem **apenas** dentro do APK gerado (elas não existem na árvore do Android Studio nem na pasta do meu projeto) :/

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Entendi, mas é isto mesmo, para dar compatibilidade o APK acaso esteja usando o Material Design é necessário criar estas pastas. Editei a resposta, removi a parte inicial da resposta que confundiu um pouco :) - desculpe

Comment: Interessante esse comportamento! Digo isso porque não uso Material Design nem Material Theme em meu app, e não uso **nenhuma** lib daquelas `compat` e `support`. Ainda assim ele cria as pastas... e cria as pastas para versões aparentemente aleatórias (`v11`, `v14` e `v17`) :( O mais preocupante, é que a pasta `xml` (para quem ele gera as versões `v14` e `v17`) sequer contém layout! :(

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn e isso a final de contas irá te prejudicar em quê? o seu `apk` ficará mais pesado?

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn se as pastas estão lá deve ser porque o Android Studio necessita delas.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira Na verdade, fica sim. Ele cria cópia dos layouts, removendo alguns atributos de API's novas dos arquivos nas pastas de API's mais antigas, atributos os quais não fariam mal algum se continuassem lá, conforme eu explico na seção "Atualização", de junho de 2015. Realmente resolvi utilizando as build-tools `20.0.0`. Como não fiz mais testes, não publiquei como resposta, e por isso, não marquei a pergunta como fechada :)